# strange calculate data on a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, plsql, sybase

I have a table like this

```
Table1(A,B)

A    B
3    0
4    3
2    2
0    1
3    5
4    6
.    .
.    .
.    .
.    .
```

It has about 3 million rows. I want to calculate this:

A_SUM = 3*(3+2+1+5+6+.......) + 4*(2+1+5+6+........) + 2*(1+5+6+...) + 0*(5+6+...) 
+ 3*(6+...) + ........

B_SUM = 0*(4+2+0+3+4+.......) + 3*(2+0+3+4+........) + 2*(0+3+4+...) + 1*(3+4+...) 
+ 5*(4+...) + ............

How can I calculate this data?

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: In fact I will do it on sybase. But I only want to learn algorithm about this problem. Thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want with a cumulative sum.  The following syntax is ANSI standard and should work (depending on the version of your database):

```
select sum(a*(revcumb - b)) as a_sum, sum(b*(revcuma - a)) as b_sum
from (select t.*,
             sum(b) over (order by id desc) as revcumb,
             sum(a) over (order by id desc) as revcuma
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Note that instead of using `rows between` or `range between`, this just subtracts the value in the current row from the (reverse) cumulative sum.

Also note that this assumes the presence of an id column or some other column to specify the ordering of rows.  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so you need a column to specify ordering, when that is important.

And, if you don't have cumulative sum (i.e. SQL Server < 2012), then you can do the same thing with correlated subqueries.

EDIT:

Sybase may or may not support the above.  There are so many different versions of that database that it is hardly worth anything as a tag.  I think this will work on most versions:

```
select sum(a*revcumb) as a_sum, sum(b*revcuma) as b_sum
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(b) from table t2 where t2.id > t.id) as revcumb,
             (select sum(a) from table t2 where t2.id > t.id) as revcuma
      from table t
     ) t;
```